# Ansible installation problem (python-paramiko)

Tags: python, ansible

I'm trying to install ansible at ubuntu 20.04, but I'm getting the following error:

```
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ansible : Depends: python-paramiko but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have python 2.7.18.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, `python-paramiko` seems to be only available on the Bionic version (Ubuntu 18.03).

1. You can try downloading the **python-paramiko** package from [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/search/?q=paramiko). Install it with `dpkg -i <package_name.deb>` and then type the install command `apt install ansible`;
2. You can try adding the bionic repositories to your `sources.list` at `/etc/apt/sources.list` (I don't recommend this);

I was able to install this package by installing `python3-paramiko` (`apt install python3-paramiko`) or `python3-spur` (`apt install python3-spur`)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But python3-paramiko has been installed already, but I still get the error. ANy other ideas?

Comment: Did you try to install the package from the provided pkgs.org link (https://pkgs.org/search/?q=paramiko) ?

Comment: If your system architecture is 64 bits, try downloading from [this link](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/paramiko/python-paramiko_2.0.0-1ubuntu1_all.deb) - I got this link from pkgs.org - and installing it with `sudo dpkg -i python-paramiko_2.0.0-1ubuntu1_all.deb`